# How can I plot two series from different data frames against each other with ggplot2 in R without building a new data frame?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dataframe

Suppose that I have two data frames

```
df1 = data.frame(x=1:10)
df2 = data.frame(x=11:20)
```

and I want a scatter plot with these two series defining the coordinates. It would be simple to do

```
plot(df1$x,df2$x)
```

From what I can tell so far about ggplot2, I could also do

```
df = data.frame(x1 = df1$x, x2 = df2$x)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=x1, y=x2)) + geom_point()
rm(df)
```

but that would be slower (for me) than not creating a new data frame, is hard to read, and could lead to increased mistakes (deleting the wrong data frame, writing over a needed data frame, forgetting to remove the excess clutter, etc.). Do I really need to create a separate data frame just to house the data that are already there? Why does the first line of the following work even though it only lists one of the data frames under "data" while the second line does not?

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes(x=df1$x, y=df2$x)) + geom_point()
ggplot(            aes(x=df1$x, y=df2$x)) + geom_point()
```

Here is an example image of basically what I want:
[image: Desired output]

Comment: How about `ggplot(data.frame(x=df1$x, y=df2$x), aes(x,y)) + geom_point()`?

Comment: You could do the following, `ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=df1$x, y=df2$x))`, `ggplot(data=NULL, aes(x=df1$x, y=df2$x)) + geom_point()`, if you insist on not creating another `data.frame`

Comment: All three of those work.

Comment: @randy you know that ggplot is just making another data frame anyway, right?

Comment: Sure, but coming from using `plot(df1$x,df2$x)` and trying to convert my code to make use of ``ggplot` is a nightmare that would be so much worse if I needed to take each of my hundred 4000x100 dimension data frames corresponding to different experiments and then manage thousands more built just for individual plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any line of the following (all taken from comments) should work:

```
ggplot(data=data.frame(x=df1$x, y=df2$x), aes(x,y)) + geom_point()

ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=df1$x, y=df2$x))

ggplot(data=NULL, aes(x=df1$x, y=df2$x)) + geom_point()

ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=x)) + geom_point(aes(y=df2$x))
```

I prefer the last line (taken from a comment that was deleted). As mentioned in comments on the question, `ggplot()` will create a `data.frame` anyway. What these solutions do is permit the user to ignore this aspect of data management somewhat (admittedly in ways that some users would find abhorrent).

Comment: I have the same issue @randy. But I have multiple columns from each dataframes that I need to put on the same plot. How should I plot that?

Comment: Can you clarify your question, @Jack? This might need to be a new question.

Comment: Jack, you can specify data and aesthetic arguments for each geom separately.

Answer (score 0):

This was going to be a comment, but I'm not reputable enough yet.

You could also try `qplot(x = df1$x, y = df2$x)`. Note that from `?qplot` that qplot will create a data frame for you from the inputs provided, if the data argument is left unset.

Comment: ggplot also creates a data frame as well even when you specify a data frame. qplot is a junior demon spawn in ggplot that rly shld not be used (said fact is emphasized in the upcoming update to the official ggplot2 book).