# How to use a cutoff date slider input in the shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I am in the midst of creating a shiny app to help have my data frame go from this...

```
         Date Street Name State  Cars on Road  Accidents
0  2001-10-01    A Street    MD          3572          1
1  2001-10-02    B Street    MD          1624          1
2  2001-10-03    C Street    MD          1085          0
3  2001-10-04    D Street    MD          5017          0
4  2001-10-05    E Street    MD          2335          1
5  2001-10-06    F Street    MD          1664          0
6  2001-10-07    G Street    MD          5762          0
7  2001-10-08    H Street    MD          3422          0
8  2001-10-09    I Street    MD          1127          1
9  2001-10-10    J Street    MD          4066          1
10 2001-10-11    A Street    MD          4916          1
11 2001-10-12    B Street    MD          5432          1
12 2001-10-13    C Street    MD          1619          1
13 2001-10-14    D Street    MD          1714          1
14 2001-10-15    E Street    MD          3423          0
15 2001-10-16    F Street    MD          1284          0
16 2001-10-17    G Street    MD          4383          0
17 2001-10-18    H Street    MD          3459          0
18 2001-10-19    I Street    MD          1822          1
19 2001-10-20    J Street    MD          2356          1
```

To this as a result of a sliderInput from shiny setting a cutoff date for before and after "October 10th, 2001"...

```
   Street Name  State  Cars_on_Road.x  Total_Accidents.x  Accident_Rate.x  Cars_on_Road.y  Total_Accidents.y  Accident_Rate.y  Total_Number_of_Cars_on_Road
1     A Street     MD            3572                 1          25.572            4916            0                         0.000  8488
2     B Street     MD            1624                 1          38.799            5432            1                        10.035  7056
3     C Street     MD            1085                 0          33.169            1619            1                        42.596  2704
4     D Street     MD            5017                 0           6.520            1714            1                        40.942  6731
5     E Street     MD            2335                 1          30.978            3423            0                         0.000  5758
6     F Street     MD            1664                 0          21.968            1284            0                         0.000  2947
7     G Street     MD            5762                 0           4.461            4383            0                         0.000  10145
8     H Street     MD            3422                 0          13.381            3459            0                         0.000  6881
9     I Street     MD            1128                 1          56.947            1822            1                        29.674  2950
10    J Street     MD            4066                 1          13.822            2356            1                            28.721  6422
```

However, I have been struggling to make the database look exactly like this via shiny.

**EDIT #1**

If I don't use shiny, this is exactly how I would create the second database from the first database. Blunty, I have been having a miserable time figuring out how to put the reactive code in the server portion of the shiny code that I don't have any idea how to make it.

```
raw_data <- read_csv("C:\\mypath\\myfile.txt")

before_date <- raw_data %>% filter(Date <= as.Date("2001-10-10")) %>% summarize(Cars_on_Road = sum(raw_data$"Cars on Road"), Total_Accidents = sum(Accidents)) %>% mutate(Accident_Rate = round(Total_Accidents/Cars_on_Road*100000,3))
after_date <- raw_data %>% filter(Date > as.Date("2001-10-10")) %>% summarize(Cars_on_Road = sum(raw_data$"Cars on Road"), Total_Accidents = sum(Accidents)) %>% mutate(Accident_Rate = round(Total_Accidents/Cars_on_Road*100000,3))

final <- merge.data.frame(x = before_date, y = after_date, by = "Street Name", all = TRUE) %>% mutate(Total_Cars_on_Road = Cars_on_Road.x + Cars_on_Road.y)
```

What are your suggestions to this? Any assistance is truly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share your current code? It's hard to see without it why your code is not giving you the expected results.

Comment: To @PaulvanOppen, see edit above.

Comment: sorry to be a pain but can you either add code that creates your DF or copy the result of a `dput` function here? Otherwise I have to manually type in your DF to help you.

Comment: @PaulvanOppen here's another way to put this, what I'm trying to do is make a shiny scatter plot exactly like this example  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321396/how-can-i-plot-two-series-from-different-data-frames-against-each-other-with-ggp) but with a cutoff date as a slider tool. I want my x value to be the accident rate before the cutoff date and the y-value to be the accident rate after the cutoff date. That's why I'm trying to figure out how to properly organize the data exactly the way I want it so that it can react to the slider tool properly.

Comment: there are 3 steps then. Step 1: Take your original data and filter it by date range (from shiny sliders). Step 2: reshape your data to make it appropriate for plotting as a scatter plot (using any of the numeric columns). Step 3: plot using ggplot2 and display in your shiny application. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a bit with your question as the data is a little strange in my view: why does not each street have accident and car date for each day but for pairs of days with 10 days in between?
But given this I did try to come up with a way around it. The main challenge was to separate the columns into two for each group (streets).

First, set up the main objects and call the libraries:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

set.seed(123)

data <- tibble( # a tibble that looks like yours
  date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020/02/01"), length.out = 20, by ="day"),
  street_name = rep(LETTERS[1:10], 2),
  cars = round(runif(n = 20, min = 3000, max = 5000), digits = 0),
  accidents = round(runif(n = 20, min = 0, max = 1), digits = 0)
)

start.date = as.Date("2020/02/01")
end.date = as.Date("2020/02/10")

size <- nrow(data)
```

Then I need group the data by street_name, work out which are the first and second (last) row in each group, then change to a wide shape and recombine. Strange code...

```
data <- data %>%
  filter(date >= start.date & date <= end.date) %>% # set date range
  group_by(street_name) %>%
  mutate(group = row_number()) %>% # number rows by group
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, # split to columns with column names by group
              values_from = c(cars, accidents)) %>%
  mutate(cars_1 = first(cars_1), # recombine data 
         cars_2 =  last(cars_2),
         accidents_1 = first(accidents_1),
         accidents_2 = last(accidents_2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  slice(1:(size/2)) # we only need first (or last) half of tibble
```

Then things become easy:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(accident_rate_1 = accidents_1 / cars_1,
         accident_rate_2 = accidents_2 / cars_2,
         total_cars_on_road = cars_1 + cars_2)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = accident_rate_1, accident_rate_2)) +
  geom_point()
```

Not sure if this is what you were after, hope it helps.